# Tensorflow Playground customized tool

Tags: javascript, html, data-visualization, data-analysis

I am in need of a [Tensorflow Playground](http://playground.tensorflow.org) kind of tool that will help me in visual analytics. If possible it must be using Tensorflow. Also, it should load inputs and output from the file. If not from the file atleast it should be multi dimensional and not like playground which is just 2 dimensional in nature.
Please let me know if there is any. or tell me how can I customize or if anyone can customize to satisfy my requirements.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what is your final goal. Do you want to train a neural network? Do you want to display information? Also, should the tool be an existing webapp, or a webapp to run on your server, or a library to integrate into your own webapp?

Comment: Please accept my apologize. If you see the playground app. It is already a web app which shown visual analytics of different Algorithms like classification and the regression as given by Tensorflow. I am need of visualization using the tensorflow.js and input must be more than 2D. I will create my training model after I analyze the data using that Webapp. If possible then it should be open source. If not no worries.